# Magento2 search like searching using REST API

Tags: magento2, api, catalogsearch

When using magento search REST API you can search with **logical AND search**

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/howdoi/webapi/search-criteria.html#logical-and-search

For example I want to search all product that contains shower **and** bath in the name. With an api request this is pretty simple.

```
http://local.webshop/rest/V1/products?
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=name&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=%25bath%25&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=like&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][field]=name&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][value]=%25shower%25&
    searchCriteria[filter_groups][1][filters][0][condition_type]=like
```

Now I want to search like this in my magento2 website using the default search input text. I don't want to make an API request. How would I change this? The default magento search functionality uses **Logical OR search**

I updated the **_renderFiltersBefore()** in `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection`

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
protected function _renderFiltersBefore()
{
    $this->getSearchCriteriaBuilder();
    $this->getFilterBuilder();
    $this->getSearch();

    $priceRangeCalculation = $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Dynamic\AlgorithmFactory::XML_PATH_RANGE_CALCULATION,
        \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
    );

    $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();

    $this->filterGroupBuilder = ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('\Magento\Framework\Api\Search\FilterGroupBuilder');
    /*
    Filter 1
     */
    $filter1 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('search_term')
        ->setValue('bath')
        ->create();
    $filterGroup1 = $this->filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($filter1)->create();

    /*
    Filter 2
     */
    $filter2 = $this->filterBuilder->setField('search_term')
        ->setValue('tap')
        ->create();
    $filterGroup2 = $this->filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($filter2)->create();

    if ($priceRangeCalculation) {
        $priceFilter = $this->filterBuilder->setField('price_dynamic_algorithm')
        ->setValue($priceRangeCalculation)
        ->create();
        $filterPriceGroup = $this->filterGroupBuilder->addFilter($priceFilter)->create();
    }

    $searchCriteria->setFilterGroups([$filterPriceGroup, $filterGroup2, $filterGroup1]);
    $searchCriteria->setRequestName($this->searchRequestName);

    try {
        $this->searchResult = $this->getSearch()->search($searchCriteria);
    } catch (EmptyRequestDataException $e) {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Api\Search\SearchResultInterface $searchResult */
        $this->searchResult = $this->searchResultFactory->create()->setItems([]);
    } catch (NonExistingRequestNameException $e) {
        $this->_logger->error($e->getMessage());
        throw new LocalizedException(__('Sorry, something went wrong. You can find out more in the error log.'));
    }

    $temporaryStorage = $this->temporaryStorageFactory->create();
    $table = $temporaryStorage->storeApiDocuments($this->searchResult->getItems());

    $this->getSelect()->joinInner(
        [
            'search_result' => $table->getName(),
        ],
        'e.entity_id = search_result.' . TemporaryStorage::FIELD_ENTITY_ID,
        []
    );

    $this->_totalRecords = $this->searchResult->getTotalCount();

    if ($this->order && 'relevance' === $this->order['field']) {
        $this->getSelect()->order('search_result.'. TemporaryStorage::FIELD_SCORE . ' ' . $this->order['dir']);
    }
    return parent::_renderFiltersBefore();
}
```

This is not returning the expected results.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this question here (that I made):
[Magento 2.1.6 Product Grid page count and record count issue when programmatically adding filter using different methods](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/172690/magento-2-1-6-product-grid-page-count-and-record-count-issue-when-programmatical)

I explore several different solutions to add filters (with the AND logical operator) to the Product Collection. See my answer to the question for the final solution.